# Conversion fails between nullable double and int

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I have a model, `FittingProject`, which I'm trying to map to another model, `FittingsProjectSharepointModel`.

Unfortunately `FittingProject` and `FittingsProjectSharepointModel` only share values, both property names and types are different.

To ease the mapping process I have created a custom attribute for `FittingProject` which I use to look up the matching property on `FittingsProjectSharepointModel`. The problem is that most values fail during conversion, for example going from `int` to `double?`.

As you can see by snippet below I have attempt to use the `Convert.ChangeType`, but it still fails with the same Exception.

```
public ModelMapper MapModelToFittingsProjectSharepointModel(object model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var propertiesWithCustomAttributes = model
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SharepointModelPropertyAttribute), true).Length > 0);

    foreach (var prop in propertiesWithCustomAttributes)
    {
        foreach (var customAttribute in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            SharepointModelPropertyAttribute sharePointModelPropertyAttribute = 
                customAttribute as SharepointModelPropertyAttribute;

            PropertyDescriptor sharePointModelprop = TypeDescriptor
                .GetProperties(typeof(FittingsProjectSharepointModel))
                .Find(sharePointModelPropertyAttribute.SharepointModelProperty, false);

            try
            {
                var projectValue = prop.GetValue(model);
                var projectValueConverted = Convert.ChangeType(projectValue, sharePointModelprop.PropertyType);

                sharePointModelprop.SetValue(FittingsProjectSharepointModel, projectValueConverted);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // 
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChangeType does not support that:

```
Convert.ChangeType(1234, typeof(double)) //works
Convert.ChangeType(1234, typeof(double?)) //fails
```

So you probably need to do your own nullable processing. Simply strip away the nullable property from the destination type using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`. You also need to handle the case, that the value to be converted is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). Like this:

Consider the following example models:

```
public class FittingProject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class FittingsProjectSharepointModel
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public double? Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can create a map between the models like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<FittingProject, FittingsProjectSharepointModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Display, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name)) //Map Name to Display
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Volume, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Size)); //Map Size to Volume
```

And here is how you can convert:

```
FittingProject fitting_project = new FittingProject()
{
    Name ="project_name",
    Size = 16
};

FittingsProjectSharepointModel sharepoint_model =
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<FittingsProjectSharepointModel>(fitting_project);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However this approach would require quite a lot of refactoring and isn't really something which I can consider. However, I will think about using AutoMapper next time.